# Setting the ID for a route that can be detected on route change

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'd like to specify the ID of a selected router link.

I'm subscribing to the router events as follows:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         this.selectMenuItem(val.id);
      }
    });
}
```

which is linked to the following HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-container" *ngFor="let item of menuItems"(click)="toggleMenu($event)" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
    #rla="routerLinkActive">
  <p class="dropdown-button"><i ngClass="{{item.style}}" ></i> {{item.caption}} {{ rla.isActive ? '*' : ''}}</p>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
      <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems" [routerLink]="subItem.link">{{subItem.caption}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

when I get my even the value of val is as follows:

```
NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/settings/location", urlAfterRedirects: "/settings/location"}
```

My question is how do I setup the HTML so that the value in id is the value contained in {{subItem.id}}

Comment: Not sure what you mean in your comments below about "influence it". Do you maybe mean "magically append" without specifying in the `routerLink` somehow? Your question could be clearer about what you are expecting. If it's just a positional parameter in the URL then you can simply do `[routerLink]="[subitem.link, subItem.id]"` or `"[subItem.link, { id: subItem.id }]"` for a parameter style.

Comment: I mean that when the NavigationEnd event fires that the id has the same value as subItem.id. If I do [subitem.link, subItem.id] then it alters the URL which is not what I want to happen.

Comment: So when you were asked to explain better, then consider *"How do I pass in the `id` value so that this is visible within the router event"?*. And that is what is really missing from your thought process and question. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'id' in the router event is the *navigation* id. It's used to uniquely identify a navigation so that you can associate a NavigationStart event with a NavigationEnd event, for example. You can't repurpose it to mean something else.

You should be passing your subItem id as a route param or query param. Simple example:

```
<li [routerLink]="subItem.link" [queryParams]="{'subItemId': subItem.id}">
```

Then in your router event subscription you can look for the subItemId on the end of the url.

Comment: I had considered that but was hoping to actually set the ID as its always there and would be cleaner if I could just influence it

Comment: You can't set the ID. If you want to see where that field comes from you can search the angular repo on GitHub for 'scheduleNavigation'.